# jQuery datepicker how to find the next available date

Tags: jquery, default, datapicker, mindate

I have searched and found a few similar questions, but not a good solid answer for this one:

I am using the datepicker to select a order/delivery date. I need to know the next available date based on what the calendar shows and show it in the input field and as minDate.

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker0" ).datepicker({
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: new Date(2013, 9, 22),
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         var day = date.getDay();
         var fulldate =  date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
         return [(day == 1 ||day == 2 ||day == 3 ||day == 4 ||day == 5 ||day == 6 ||day == 0 ) && (fulldate != '22-10-2013' &&fulldate != '23-10-2013' )];
      }
   }); 

});
```

Comment: Anybody that can help? :-(